# Views BEF checkbox count in drupal 7

Tags: theming, views

I have created views with BEF check boxes as a filter criteria.

I want to get count of each check boxes as mentioned in below image.

[image]

[Reference link](http://mikekeran.com/better-exposed-filters-for-drupal-views).

My view name is **photo_search**. So I have renamed below tpl to `views-exposed-form--photo-search.tpl`

> I have copied views-exposed-form.tpl from views/theme to
>   mytheme/templates
>   . But its not working (Cache cleared & Rescanned tpl from views).

Comment: On a side note: If you would work with facets you would have this functionality out of the box

Comment: @f0ns Is there check box option in facets?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make alter in your view and place the code.

// Set an index if there are multiple terms used.

```
    $index = 0;
    // Used for the array's string index.
    $string_index = '';
    // Continue for each vocabulary that is used.
    while (isset($form['tid' . $string_index])) {
        // Cycle through each of the terms.
        foreach ($form['tid' . $string_index]['#options'] as $tid => $option) {
            // Build a query to get the nodes for this term that have been
            // specified as filters.
            $query = db_select('node', 'n')
                    ->fields('n', array('title'))
                    ->condition('n.type', $form_state['view']->display_handler->handlers['filter']['type']->value, 'IN')
                    ->condition('fa.field_advertisements_value', 'forsale', '=')
                    ->condition('ti.tid', $tid, '=');
            // A quirk in db_select(). You need to add the join separately.
            $query->innerJoin('taxonomy_index', 'ti', 'ti.nid = n.nid');
            $query->innerJoin('field_data_field_advertisements', 'fa', 'fa.entity_id = n.nid');
            $results = $query->execute();
            $count = $results->rowCount();
```

// get the count of nodes or watever with your costom query

```
            $val = $form['tid' . $string_index]['#options'][$tid];
            $form['tid' . $string_index]['#options'][$tid] = str_replace("<span>(" . $count . ")</span><span>(" . $count . ")</span>", "<span>(" . $count . ")</span>", $val . '<span>(' . $count . ')</span>');
        }
        // Increment for the next tid index in the array.
        $index += 1;
        $string_index = '-' . $index;
        //$string_index = '_' . $index;
```